# db_query throws error using SQL code with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have used similar code lots of times in the past but I'm not sure why I'm having an error this time. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
email_message_ids = tuple([int(x) for x in df_emails_postgres_pub_year['id'].values])

sql = """
SELECT 
    ut.value,
    count(DISTINCT ef.user_id) AS email_recipients,
    count(DISTINCT ef.email_message_id) AS emails_sent,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ef.clicked_at IS NOT NULL
            AND NOT ef.unsubscribe_click THEN
            ef.email_message_id
        END) AS emails_clicked,
    cast(emails_sent / email_recipients::float AS decimal(4, 2)) AS emails_per_user,
    cast(cast(100 * emails_clicked / emails_sent::float AS decimal(4, 2)) AS varchar) || '%' AS ctr
FROM
    email_funnel_2023 ef
        JOIN user_tests ut ON ef.user_id = ut.user_id
            AND ut.test = 'mentions_alert_send_paper_matches_fast'
WHERE ef.email_message_id in %(email_message_ids)s
group by 1
order by 1;
"""

df_emails_performance = db_query('redshift', sql, params={'email_message_ids': email_message_ids[:10]})
```

and here's the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2055         try:
-> 2056             cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   2057             return cur

TypeError: dict is not a sequence

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-cf8f9610a342> in <module>
     21 """
     22 
---> 23 df_emails_performance = db_query('redshift', sql, params={'email_message_ids': email_message_ids[1]})
     24 df_emails_performance

~/premium-analysis/notebooks/../src/data/db_connect.py in db_query(db_name, query, conn_kwargs, verbose, load_file, save_file, params, chunk_size, **kwargs)
    223                         sys.stdout.flush()
    224             if df is None:
--> 225                 df = sql_query(conn, query, params=params, **kwargs)
    226 
    227         conn.rollback()

~/premium-analysis/notebooks/../src/data/db_connect.py in sql_query(conn, query, params, **kwargs)
    255     """
    256     try:
--> 257         df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params, **kwargs)
    258         return df
    259 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    600 
    601     if isinstance(pandas_sql, SQLiteDatabase):
--> 602         return pandas_sql.read_query(
    603             sql,
    604             index_col=index_col,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize, dtype)
   2114 
   2115         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 2116         cursor = self.execute(*args)
   2117         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   2118 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2066 
   2067             ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")
-> 2068             raise ex from exc
   2069 
   2070     @staticmethod

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
SELECT 
    ut.value,
    count(DISTINCT ef.user_id) AS email_recipients,
    count(DISTINCT ef.email_message_id) AS emails_sent,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ef.clicked_at IS NOT NULL
            AND NOT ef.unsubscribe_click THEN
            ef.email_message_id
        END) AS emails_clicked,
    cast(emails_sent / email_recipients::float AS decimal(4, 2)) AS emails_per_user,
    cast(cast(100 * emails_clicked / emails_sent::float AS decimal(4, 2)) AS varchar) || '%' AS ctr
FROM
    email_funnel_2023 ef
        JOIN user_tests ut ON ef.user_id = ut.user_id
            AND ut.test = 'mentions_alert_send_paper_matches_fast'
WHERE ef.email_message_id in %(email_message_ids)s
group by 1
order by 1;
': dict is not a sequence
```

Would anyone know what may be going on here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `'%'` to `'%%'`.